# Working with small probabilities, via logs

Tags: algorithm, precision, logarithm

Source: Google Code Jam. https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/10224486/dashboard#s=a&a=1

We're asked to calculate Prob(K successes from N trials) where each of the N trials has a known success probability of p_n.

Some Analysis and thoughts on the problem are given after the Code Jam.

They observe that evaluating all possible outcomes of your N trials would take you an exponential time in N, so instead they provide a nice "dynamic programming" style solution that's O(N^2).

Let P(p#q) = Prob(p Successes after the first q Trials)
Then observe the fact that:

```
Prob(p#q) = Prob(qth trial succeeds)*P(p-1#q-1) + Prob(qth trial fails)*P(p#q-1)
```

Now we can build up a table of P(i#j) where i<=j, for i = 1...N

That's all lovely - I follow all of this and could implement it.

---

Then as the last comment, they say:

```
In practice, in problems like this, one should store the logarithms of
probabilities instead of the actual values, which can become small
enough for floating-point precision errors to matter.
```

I think I broadly understand the point they're trying to make, but I specifically can't figure out how to use this suggestion.

Taking the above equation, and substuting in some lettered variables:

```
P = A*B + C*D
```

If we want to work in Log Space, then we have:

```
Log(P) = Log(A*B + C*D),
```

where we have recursively pre-computed `Log(B)` and `Log(D)`, and `A` & `B` are known, easily-handled decimals.

But I don't see any way to calculate `Log(P)` without just doing `e^(Log(B))`, etc. which feels like it would defeat to point of working in log space`?

Does anyone understand in better detail what I'm supposed to be doing?

Comment: The updated link is: https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/0000000000201c91/0000000000201d1e#analysis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from the initial relation:

P = A⋅B + C⋅D

Due to its symmetry we can assume that B is larger than D, without loss of generality.
The following processing is useful:

log(P) = log(A⋅B + C⋅D) = log(A⋅e<sup>log(B)</sup> + C⋅e<sup>log(D)</sup>) = log(e<sup>log(B)</sup>⋅(A + C⋅e<sup>log(D) - log(B)</sup>)

log(P) = log(B) + log(A + C⋅e<sup>log(D) - log(B)</sup>).

This is useful because, in this case, log(B) and log(D) are both negative numbers (logarithms of some probabilities). It was assumed that B is larger than D, thus its log is closer to zero. Therefore log(D) - log(B) is still negative, but not as negative as log(D).

So now, instead of needing to perform exponentiation of log(B) and log(D) separately, we only need to perform exponentiation of log(D) - log(B), which is a mildly negative number. So the above processing leads to better numerical behavior than using logarithms and applying exponentiation in the trivial way, or, equivalently, than not using logarithms at all.

Comment: oooh!!! Right, yes, of course. Thank you, a very clear explanation of the process. Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome :) the explanation of the problem was very clear as well! (otherwise, if I would just have seen the remark from code jam, i'm not sure i would realize this approach).